# How to manage Python versions for a virtualenv in my open source project?

Tags: python, makefile, virtualenv, pyenv

I have an open source project called [Djengu](https://github.com/johnckealy/djengu). To install it, the user must clone the repo and run `make` to initiate the setup script. The setup script creates a Python virtual environment using `virtualenv`. The command goes like

```
virtualenv -p python3.8 .python3.8_env
```

I'd like to pin the Python version to avoid anything breaking. I also cannot assume that any given user will have a `python3.8` binary installed on their machine. And I cannot assume that they have `pyenv` installed either.

I imagine I will have to make a trade off somewhere. How can I pin Python without making assumptions on what the user has installed? Is there a standard way to do something like this?

Comment: Typically, you don't, short of shipping the required version with the rest of your software. Simply document that Python 3.8 (or higher, presumably) is required, and let the user be responsible for ensuring that it is installed in whatever way they like.

Answer (score 1):

Since your Djengu project is a development environment, I think it's completely fine to require that your users first install `pyenv` before calling `make`. Just tell them to do so in the Readme. You can then use their `pyenv` in your `Makefile` to install the Python version you need.